# How to format output linux script result

Tags: linux, bash, format

I have a project to execute a script and need to `format the output`, **including unexpected errors**. I know that I can use `trap` to intercept errors, so I tried to use it to format the output, the `example` is as follows

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -o errtrace
status=false
trap "print " ERR

print() {
    echo "{\"status\":$status,\"result\":\"$1\"}"
    exit 0
}

main(){
    arg=$1
    if [ "$arg" == "0" ];then
        status=true
        print "successfully finish"
    else
        cat /a/b/c/d >>/dev/null
        echo "abnormal termination"
    fi
}

main "$@"
```

The logic of success meets my needs as follows

```bash
# bash format-print.sh 0
{"status":true,"result":"successfully finish"}
```

But when an exception error is caught it doesn't meet my needs

```bash
# bash format-print.sh 1
cat: /a/b/c/d: No such file or directory
{"status":false,"result":""}
```

I would like to enter the following result

```bash
# bash format-print.sh 1
cat: /a/b/c/d: No such file or directory
{"status":false,"result":"cat: /a/b/c/d: No such file or directory"}
```

How can I modify the code to meet my needs, and if trap does not work or is not the standard way, can you please tell me how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you need is to capture the error output from your command so that you can include it in your formatted output. You don't need a trap for this, although if you wanted to use a trap to invoke `print` you could do that (maybe with `EXIT` instead of `ERR` though).

With direct calls to the `print` function, this will do what you're looking for:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o errtrace
status=false
#trap "print " ERR # removed trap for testing

print() {
    echo "{\"status\":$status,\"result\":\"$1\"}"
    exit 0
}

main(){
    arg=$1
    if [ "$arg" == "0" ];then
        status=true
        print "successfully finish"
    else
        # captures stderr into a variable while discarding stdout
        result=$( cat /a/b/c/d 2>&1 >/dev/null )
        print "$result"
    fi
}

main "$@"
```

This will provide the output:

```
$ ./test.sh 1
{"status":false,"result":"cat: /a/b/c/d: No such file or directory"}
```

Comment: Sorry, I also wanted to capture `unexpected errors`. Your method can solve `predictable errors`

Comment: What do you mean by "unexpected errors"? This will capture errors whether you expect them or not. Either way you have to capture the errors yourself by redirecting them somewhere, there's no history of error messages you can dig back into if you're just sending them to the terminal.